# How should I choose who will be murdered?

Tags: wolfenstein-the-new-order

I'm only about an hour into *Wolfenstein: The New Order* and my men were just captured by General Deathshead. He demanded that I choose which of my teammates he would dissect or else promised to kill them both.

I chose the guy on the right. When the cutscene ended, I unlocked the "Wyatt Timeline" which says I can pick locks now. Was this because of my choice? What would have happened if I'd made the other choice, or refused to choose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you unlocked lock-picking because of your choice.

If you save the other guy ([Fergus Reid](http://wolfenstein.wikia.com/wiki/Fergus_Reid)) you get the ability to hotwire.

If you refuse, all 3 of you get killed (you are forced to make a choice).

Comment: Additionally, picking Wyatt gives you the opportunity to find hidden armor upgrades during selected chapters. Saving Fergus changes this to be health upgrades.